# Jest does not fail test when function called with invalid parameters

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am using Jest to write some unit test for a react app with typescript. When I run a test case with invalid function parameters, the test passes anyway. Suppose I have the following function:

```
function someFunction(a: number, b: number) {
 return a + b;
}
```

The supposedly erroneous test function would be:

```
it("should fail", () => someFunction());
```

I would expect the test to fail due to invalid arguments to the function. What am I missing? Of course, when I try to compile the app it would throw an error, but while I'm running npm test / yarn test I would like to monitor my tests as well.

Answer (score 0):

it's not failing because you are not having any assertions.your test should be something like:

```
it("should fail", () => {expect(someFunction(1,2)).toEqual(5)}); //here your test should fail
```